# PagedList MVC causing strange image positioning issue within Bootstrap row

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, pagedlist

**Question Background:**

I have a web page that uses Pagedlist MVC for the pagination of images. This also uses Bootstrap to render the images as responsive

**The Issue:**

I have the code set to display 9 items per page. This is working but it is causing the images to display in a 'broken' manner, as shown:

[image]

**Obviously I want these images displayed in a continuous manner.**

I orginally thought it was a sizing issue so set them to 100px as shown but this is obviously not the issue:

**The Code:**

The HTML markup:

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        @for (int i = 0; i < @Model.Count; i++)
        {

                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="imageBottomPadding imageWidths">
                        <a href="#" data-featherlight="@Model[i]">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="@Model[i]" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

        }

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
        @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Projects", new { pageNo = page }))
    </div>
</div>

<style>

.imageWidths
{

    width:100px;
}

.imageBottomPadding
 {
     padding-bottom:20px;
 }

</style>
```

The Action Method on the controller:

```
   [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Projects(int pageNo = 0)
    {
        if (pageNo == 0)
        {
            pageNo = 1;
        }

        var imagesList = _galleryHandler.GetGalleryImages();

        return View(imagesList.ToPagedList(pageNo, 9));
    }
```

Any help with solving this issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: markup seems a little off.. might want to put your pager in a `<div class="row">`  other than that it just looks like the first 2 images have some extra space at the bottom pushing the fouth image out to the right.

Comment: @JamieD77 thanks for your great reply. You were correct the first 2 images were ever so slightly taller throwing the others off. I have now set a height and width property to the div and that solves it. Please set this as your answer and I'll mark it correct.